# get screen width using less angular

Tags: javascript, css, less, angular-ui-grid

I am using a ui-grid to show the data. My requirement is that I want to set the width of grid in pixels dynamically based on the screen size. **I don't want to specify width in percentage**.

Is there any way we can get width dynamically in less (css) and set the width of grid class.

`.grid{
       width: <width in pixels> 
       }`

One thing I did using jquery in javascript code is:
    
    `let width = $(window).width();
    let grid = angular.element(document.querySelector('.grid'));
    grid.css('width', width);`

But problem with this approach I am facing is that it only works after grid is displayed. So I have to use timeout for this.

I have less exposure to this css styling side, any reference would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to `"set the width of grid in pixels dynamically based on the screen size"`? Is there a specific browser-to-screen ration that you want to have on your regression-run? Why can't adding the `--start-fullscreen` switch suffice?

Comment: No actually I am facing few issues in ui-grid if i specify width as 100%. But it is working find if I fix the width of grid. is --start-fullscreen is like F11 mode?

Comment: Yes, it's a Chrome capability to start in Full-screen mode (`F11`). For WebdriverIO it goes something like this `chromeOptions: { args: [ '--start-fullscreen'] }`. The full list of chromium switches is available **[here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)**. 
Is this something that can help you? Give me the browser stacks you're using and I can come up with an answer for configuring your options in order to start full-screen, should this be something that will help you with your problem.

Comment: Its a good option.  But this would not help me here.